# Extract date with random pattern in excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Do you have a simpler or generalized approach on extracting/formatting an excel cell in the B format. Column A have random patterns such as shown in A column.

```
A                      B
16/06/2009            6/16/2009
11/6/2009             6/11/2009
29/10/2009 13:12:51   10/29/2009 13:12:51
3/12/2009 9:38        12/3/2009  9:38
```

I tried this solution but this wont work with 2nd case.

```
B = MID($A1,4,2) & "/" & MID($A1,1,2) & "/" & MID($A1,7,4)
```

Also, Macros is not possible in my case. I am limited to native Excel functions.
Thanks.

EDIT 1: I updated the question to cover new patterns that I just learned from the data. Sorry.

EDIT 2: I found the solution, see Answer #2. It was bit brute force but it works in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have some dates in column **A** that are actually ***Text*** in dd/mm/yyyy format.

In **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),1000,999)),LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1))
```

and copy down.  Then apply the appropriate format to column **B**:

[image]

This formula will correctly process dates in column **A** with the following formats:

- d/m/yyyy
- dd/m/yyyy
- d/mm/yyyy
- dd/mm/yyyy

**EDIT#1:**

If the data in column **A** are true Excel Dates, then use this in **B1**:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response,
i have not really dig into the indexes yet, but it missed on 5/5/2009, I got #VALUE! message

Comment: @rdagumampan  the formula will work only if the material in column **A** is **Text**

Comment: this is a CSV file that I am trying to cleanup and seems excel interpret my cells randomly, some are date and some are text. Can i forced your function to take the cell sa pure text. 

I tried TEXT(x,x) but its seems not the answer.

Comment: @rdagumampan  See my **EDIT1**

Comment: You can prevent XL from interpreting some data as dates if you assign the "text" format to the first column on import. Then use Gary's second formula.

Comment: For true DATE value 5/1/2009:
Second formula returns: 5/1/2009, same value as input.

i tried to format using =TEXT(A1,"d/M/yyyy") and I get 1/5/2009 (correct). But this solution feels wrong.

Comment: Normally, if have problems with a .csv file is to rename it to a .txt then get the input wizard. In the wizard, you can specify a column as text, date, etc. Most times this is easier than cleaning up an incorrect transform for a .csv

Comment: @bvaughn, this actually works in large percentage of the values! but there were still leftovers like when i chose MDY for A column.

Values like these are left out 29/10/2009 13:12:51

Comment: What is the benefit of your last formula?  Why not use just `=A1` or `=INT (A1)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers, I managed to find a solution stated below this. A bit brute force but it works in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

slept on it and took few cups of coffee this morning and i managed to figure this out. its combination of your inputs and readings i had.

Formula as represented by these cells:

```
E2 = 27/06/2016 08:00:00
F2 = FIND("/",$E2) -> 3 the first /
G2 = FIND("/",$E2,4) -> 6 the second /
H2 = IFERROR(FIND(" ",$E2,4),0) -> 11 any presence of " " space
I2 = NUMBERVALUE(MID($E2,$F2+1,($G2-$F2)-1)) -> 6 month
J2 = NUMBERVALUE(MID($E2,1,$F2-1)) -> 27 day
K2 = NUMBERVALUE(MID($E2,$G2+1,4)) -> 2016 year
L2 = IF(H2=0,"N", "Y") -> Y time present
M2 = IF(H2=0,"00:00:00",RIGHT($E2,LEN($E2)-$H2)) -> 08:00:00 time
N2 = I2 &"/"& J2 &"/"& K2 &" "& M2 -> 6/27/2016 08:00:00 final results
```

1. From excel, I copied the entire column and paste on Notepad.
2. Format the Date (ex. E2), delete all rows and format as Text.
3. Paste all the rows from Notepad into the column E2. This forced the column to be interpreted as Text by Excel! *fck*
4. Then I had the formula, i broke them down to test if everything works for all cases.

[I shared my results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml8oM.png)